# VBA - Dynamically create Public Type variables?

Tags: vba, types, constructor, ms-word

Quick question, I've got all of these statically set `Public Type` variables in my macro code.  These are supposed to represent the values of an INI file. The way I would like it to be is that the code is all dynamic, based on what's in the INI file. So I don't need to manually update both the INI file and the code behind.

This is an outtake of the code the way it is now. This is inside it's own module:

```
Public Type Fields
     Firstname as String
     Lastname as String
     Username as String
End Type
```

I was thinking of reading the entire section of the INI file using `ReadIniSection`, but it seems as though it's not possible to do this within a `Public Type`. Am I correct? Could it be possible to get around this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Scripting.Dictionary object (set a reference to the Scripting.Runtime library).

To store:

```
oDict.Add keyName, keyValue
```

To read back:

```
oDict(keyName)
```

That's assuming you have unique key names with single values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Tim

Comment: This sounds promising! :) Do you however have an example of how I'll do this. Like a small code snippet or something? Edit: You mean using Scripting Dictionary instead of Public Type?

Comment: I think it's the ` you should use before and after the code block :) Especially in comments. But in answers you have the option to select a code snippet and format the whole thing using the toolbar in the editor.

Comment: What are the chances of a computer not having Cripting.RunTime library installed? I might have to use VBA Collections instead. If that's even possible.

Comment: @JFC - fixed code formatting.   @Kenny: I've never run across a PC not having the runtime, but then I work in a windows-only environment.  If you need to support Mac Excel then you may be out of luck with that approach...

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible (but maybe not advisable) to add code to a module programatically. Since VBA does not support reflection, this is the only type of "dynamic" coding there is in the language. This is useful in a pinch.

See the snippet below. The `addCode` sub takes a standard module's name, a `Type`'s name, and an array containing the definition of the fields.

It first tries to delete the existing `Type` with the same name, and then adds the new type definition in.

```
Sub TestAdd()
    Dim FieldArray()

    FieldArray = Array( _
     "Firstname As String", _
     "Lastname As String", _
     "Username As String" _
    )


    AddCode "Module2", "Fields", FieldArray
End Sub

Sub AddCode(ModuleName As String, TypeName As String, FieldArray())
    Dim StartLine As Long, EndLine As Long, StartColumn As Long, EndColumn As Long, _
        CodeToInsert As String

    StartLine = 1: StartColumn = -1
    EndLine = -1: EndColumn = -1

    'Find the old type definition and remove it.
    With Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName).CodeModule

        'Search for the start of the type definition
        If .Find("Public Type " & TypeName, StartLine, StartColumn, EndLine, EndColumn, True) Then
            EndLine = EndLine + 1: StartColumn = -1: EndLine = -1: EndColumn = -1

            'Found the start, now find the end of the type definition
            If .Find("End Type", EndLine, StartColumn, EndLine, EndColumn, True) Then
                .DeleteLines StartLine, (EndLine - StartLine) + 1
            End If
        End If

        CodeToInsert = _
            "Public Type " & TypeName & vbCrLf & _
            Join(FieldArray, vbCrLf) & vbCrLf & _
            "End Type"

        .InsertLines StartLine, CodeToInsert
    End With

End Sub
```